# nodejs does not emit data to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I have simple nodejs app with sockets and I've faced an error where I can't find any solution. So I'm emiting from app to client and nothing happens there. Or client can't receive it - I don't know, because I can't check if it was successfully emited to client. This is the error I got when I tried to debug callback of emit:

`Error: Callbacks are not supported when broadcasting`

This my app code:

```
    http.listen(6060, function () {
    console.log("Listening on *: 6060");
});

io.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, accept) {
    var domain = handshakeData.headers.referer.replace('http://', '').replace('https://', '').split(/[/?#]/)[0];

    if ('***' == domain) {
        accept(null, true);
    } else {
        return accept('You must be logged in to take an action in this site!', false);
    }
});

io.use(function (sock, next) {
    var handshakeData = sock.request;
    var userToken = handshakeData._query.key;

    if (typeof userToken !== null && userToken !== 0 && userToken !== '0' && userToken.length > 0) {
        connection.query('***',
            [xssfilter.filter(validator.escape(userToken))],
            function (error, data) {
                if (error) {
                    debug('Cant receive user data from database by token');
                    next(new Error('Failed to parse user data! Please login!'));
                } else {
                    // load data to this user.
                    _updateUsers(xssfilter.filter(validator.escape(userToken)), 'add', data[0], sock.id);
                    _loadPreData();

                    next(null, true);
                }
            });
    } else {
        debug('Cant receive user token');
        next(new Error('Failed to parse user data! Please login!'));
    }

    sock.on("disconnect", function () {
        _updateUsers(false, 'remove', false, sock.id);
    });
});

// we need to show people online count
io.emit('online-count', {
    count: Object.keys(connectedUsers).length
});
```

And the function used above:

```
    function _updateUsers(userToken, action, userData, sockedID) {
    switch (action) {
        case 'add':
            connectedUsers[sockedID] = {...};
            io.emit('online-count', io.emit('online-count', {
            count: Object.keys(connectedUsers).length
        }););

            break;
        case 'remove':
            delete connectedUsers[sockedID];
            io.emit('online-count', io.emit('online-count', {
            count: Object.keys(connectedUsers).length
        }););

            break;
    }
}
```

so after emiting `online-count` I should accept it on the client side as I'm doing it:

```
var socket;
socket = io(globalData.socketConn, {query: "key=" + globalData.userData.token});
socket.on('connect', function (data) {
    console.log('Client side successfully connected with APP.');
});
socket.on('error', function (err) {
    error('danger', 'top', err);
});

socket.on('online-count', function (data) {
    console.log('Got online count: ' + data.count);
    $('#online_count').html(data.count);
});
```

but the problem is with this `online-count`.. Nothing happens and it seems that it's not was even sent from node app. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my logic - I was sending online count only if new user were connecting/disconnecting. Problem were solved by adding function to repeat itself every few seconds and send online count to client side.